# Want to know after death

Tags: afterlife

Can the soul meet the souls of his beloved ones? Can I after my death meet my parents' souls? Will they have feeling when they were alive and shall I have feeling as I have now? If yes, how the conversation takes place?

Comment: You can refer the following question for some guidance https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28096/do-our-parents-in-this-birth-will-be-our-parents-in-every-birth-does-this-cycle

Answer (score 1):

Hinduism generally teaches that after death, unless the person has attained enlightenment and become part of Brahman, their life force is reincarnated and they live another life on Earth. There is no such thing as a "soul" per se, as everything is part of the one Universal substance called Brahman, and thus your parents will either have returned to Brahman or been reincarnated.

There are in some circumstances heavens that are temporary locations between Earthly lives in which it is said one can meet their ancestors, this such heaven is called Pitriloka. The "soul" if you will is said to go to Pitriloka between lives if they have given gifts and made sacrifices during life, but this is not a permanent state and the person's life force will reincarnate after some time in Pitriloka.

If your parents were good religious people then it can be assumed that they are in Pitriloka for the time being, but they will not be the same. The "soul" does not experiences sensations and memories in the same way after death, and you will not "have a conversation", as you will not have a body!

It is likely that it will be like a dream state that you are all sharing.